# What is faster ASP.NET MVC or Ruby On Rails

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails

This is not meant to be a subjective or argumentative question.

I am investing some time in learning ASP.NET and more specifically ASP.NET MVC and I am curious how it stacks up to the competition. I really like what I am seeing so far with the framework, and I think the icing on the cake would be if it shows rock solid speed like I have seen with some ASP.NET form sites.

Has anyone done or seen fair comparisons or benchmarks? I would be interested to see how ASP.NET MVC stacks up against other solutions such as PHP MVC too.

Comment: This is a good objective question. You would think someone could set up the same basic Web application using various frameworks and run stress tests against each.  Here is something similar, it compares the performance of different language implementations for a variety of algorithms. http://shootout.alioth.debian.org

Answer (score 7):

If you compare just raw execution .NET is faster than PHP or RoR. However, the speed and overall performance of an application depends on its architecture. For example: StackOverflow runs on less than 10 servers. I work for a company that runs a website with pretty much the same hardware (+- 10 heavy work servers) but SO is way faster and has hundred times more access that my company's website.

So in most case it is really about how you implement the software other than the platform itself.

Comment: Indeed. Crappy code tends to run slower.

Comment: I'm not only talking about crappy code, but crappy architecture. Let's say a website has a lot of reading operations. If a slower technology implements it using cache no matter how well I implement it in my faster technology without using cache that I won't achieve the same performance ever. It's all about architecture when dealing with out of the ordinary problems.

Comment: Yeah I was going to say. How can just code be such a difference... But it looks like you opened up a whole new can of worms with this "architecture" word.

Answer (score -2):

You can not compare the language only based on speed. Each language has its own features. So you need to choose as per your requirement.

For example. If you want less spendings on hosting and other stuff then go for PHP else if you want pure MVc then gofor ruby on rails or asp.net mvc.

Comment: "less spendings on hosting and other stuff then go for PHP" -- Rails can be hosted on the same platforms as PHP.