# why is rails faster then asp.net

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was facing a decision:rails or asp.net and for some reasons i chose asp.net . I understood that rails is faster .why ?

Comment: What do you mean with 'understood'? Did you hear it from someone? What are the arguments? We can't really answer this 'question'

Comment: Are you talking development time or language-execution time?

Comment: Answer: because you are misinformed.

Comment: I've heard that the server response is much faster and also the database access is faster in rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should take a look at [What is faster ASP.NET MVC or Ruby On Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190257/what-is-faster-asp-net-mvc-or-ruby-on-rails), which also got closed

Answer (score 1):

I have never used either (I use Seaside). Before you discard me as incompetent to judge, let me tell you that that makes me unbiased!

"Faster" is what your particular benchmark says. Did you make a benchmark? Even if you did: a benchmark is first a benchmark of itself and only second a benchmark of the platform.